# Help needed in Setting up DNS Server in Windows 2008

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2000

Hi I'm trying to setup a DNS server on my loca network, so that when a client machine does
NSLOOKUP MYPCNAME
it returns the IP address of MYPCNAME

I installed DNS on the server, and I added a Forward lookup Zone named 'LAN'
Added an A record for MYPCNAME to point to 192.168.1.10

Now I can lookup the names using the fully qualified name
so NSLOOKUP MYPCNAME.LAN will return 192.168.1.10
however If i do NSLOOKUP MYPCNAME it will not return anything.

How can i configure my DNS so that NSLOOKUP MYPCNAME also returns the ip?

If I add the Forward lookup Zone as a root, then I'm able to lookup using MYPCNAME but then other name resolution over the internet do not work 'cuz the server becomes the root.

Comment: I answered this, but it really belongs on serverfault.com..

Comment: oh i didnt kow abt serverfault.com...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the DNS server that is wrong, it is your client setup.  The client machine needs a default domain name of .lan, or .lan added to the list of search suffixes in dns, to work in your configuration.